# (multiple choice) Choosing the axis to show a linear relationship when told the increase of one is proportional to the square root of the other

Tags: graphing-functions, word-problem

> **Online Test Scenario:**

A chemical reaction using a fixed amount of a compound produces heat and this is 
measured in $kCal$. When a catalyst is added to the compound the amount of heat 
produced increases. The increase in heat $(h)$ is believed to be approximately 
proportional to the square root of the mass of catalyst added $(c)$.

> **Question:**

Which one of the following plots is most likely to show a linear relationship between the variables?

1. $\sqrt{h}$ against $c$
2. $h$ against $c^{2}$
3. $h$ against $\log{}{c}$
4. $\log{}{h}$ against $\log{}{c}$

> **My attempt:**
>
> I've never come across a scenario in my studies like this (except for my masters thesis in altering axis to give a better line of best fit). Based on that logic and the wording *"increases in $h$ is proportional to the $\sqrt{c}$"* 
>   i would say the correct answer is either $1)$ or $2)$ but i don't know which or the explanation for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The words

> The increase in heat (h) is believed to be approximately proportional
>   to the square root of the mass of catalyst added (c).

expressed algebraically say that there is some constant $k$ such that
$$
h \approx k \sqrt{c}.
$$
That is clearly not a linear relationship. Squaring doesn't help, because
$$
h^2 \approx k^2c
$$
isn't linear either.

Logarithms will deal with the square root:
$$
\log h \approx \log k + (1/2)\log c .
$$
That is linear.

Comment: ah so the key is the "likely to show a linear relationship" part and then you rearrange it algebraically to make both sides of the equation "same graphically". I.e if one side is squared or square routed the line on the graph with show a polynomial graph and not that of a linear graph?

Comment: @UniStuffz Yes. Your wording is a little clumsy but the idea is right. You need a linear relationship ($y = mx + b$) between the variables on the axes.